# Sending TCP message between 2 (or more) Android device

Tags: android, networking, tcp, client-server

I'd like to send Location data from one server tablet to 1 (or more) client tablet.

**Server**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener myLocListener;
    private String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 0, myLocListener);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        NetworkThread x = new NetworkThread();
        x.start();
    }

    private class NetworkThread extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);

                Socket cl1 = ss.accept();
                PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(cl1.getOutputStream());

                while(true){
                    if(message!=null){
                            pw1.println(message);
                            pw1.flush();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

            message = "lat:" + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + " lon:" + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude() +
                    " time:" + String.valueOf(location.getTime()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView Messages;
    private Activity MainAct;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainAct = this;

        Messages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

        NetworkThread x = new NetworkThread();
        x.start();
    }

    public class NetworkThread extends Thread{

        public void run(){
            try{
                Socket s = new Socket(getIpAddress(),8080);
                final Scanner sc = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());

                while(true){
                    try{
                        MainAct.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Messages.append(sc.nextLine());
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work, the server getting the coords from the GPS, but the client doesnt receive them.

Comment: `Messages.append(sc.nextLine());`. You cannot call `sc.nextLine()` on the GUI thread. You will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` clearly visible in the logcat and your app will crash.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: what is the correct way to get the ip address for client? If the server and the client are in the same network, then enough if I use "localhost"?

Comment: `You will have a NetworkOnMainThreadException clearly visible in the logcat and your app will crash. `. Well i said that. But you did not confirm nor deny. Thats not how it goes on stackoverflow.

Comment: `what is the correct way to get the ip address for client?`. You mean: how does the client get the ip address of the server?